# download a ftp file

Tags: asp.net, ftp

I am trying to download a ftp file from my online webserver.  The file resides in ftp100-0 and is the only file in there.  The error code states:

```
The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command.
```

Here is my code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.mysite.com/"), FtpWebRequest)
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile

    ' This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("ftp100-0", "password")

    Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)

    Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd())

    Console.WriteLine("Download Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription)

    reader.Close()
    response.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the URL you are providing from a web browser to ensure it is correct. The file name is missing from the URL.

Comment: How do you add a file name?

Comment: ftp://www.mysite.com/yourfile.whatever